# Nodejs and MongoDB API on heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I'm trying to host a Nodejs API in Heroku, no matter how many solutions I try, I always get an Application error:

```
2020-11-02T15:43:59.676976+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-02T15:44:07.987404+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=intense-brook-39583.herokuapp.com request_id=b6912ee7-0d5d-4288-b31c-a960be2f94b8 fwd="186.150.39.94" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**Procfile**

```
web: node index.js
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "fullstack-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Backend en Mongo y Express",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon index.js",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "author": "enriqueMota",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.11",
    "require": "^2.4.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

**Whitelist**

```
const whitelist = ['http://localhost:4000', '0.0.0.0/0'];
```

**Mongoose connection**

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL, {
     useNewUrlParser: true,
     useUnifiedTopology: true,
     useCreateIndex: true,
     useFindAndModify: false
});
```

**localhost and port**

```
// localhost
const host = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';

// port
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.listen(port, host, () => {
     console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port} and hosted by ${host}`);
})
```

PD: I've hosted Nodejs before in Heroku, but it was a fullstack app, not an API, I've also added the config var DB_URL on Heroku to connect to the database, which is in MongoDB ATLAS, and still, it doesn't work and finally, in the localhost/postman the API works just fine, any clue what is going on or what exactly I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe try removing the space in `Procfile`. like so - `web:node app.js` but that's a long shot since their docs show the space. And maybe, move your start script to be first?

Comment: Tried both, still getting the same error

Comment: And on Heroku, host is set as 0.0.0.0 for sure?

Comment: As it turns out, no, it wasn't, I set it to 0.0.0.0 and it works now, thanks